# XQuery: compute product

Tags: xquery

I am trying to find a method like the function sum() in XQuery that performs the same thing for product. Any help with that?

```
sum(/root//elemnts)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `fold-left` e.g. `fold-left(/root//elemnts, 1, function($p, $e) { $p * $e })`.